# How to setup a webapi controller for POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a POST service that returns a List of `Tienda`. My code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<TiendaWrapper>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetTiendasPost([FromBody]Tienda t)
{
    List<Tienda> ListaTiendas = db.Tiendas.ToList();
    List<TiendaWrapper> lstTiendas = new List<TiendaWrapper>();

    foreach(Tienda T in ListaTiendas)
    {
        if (T.CodDpto == t.CodDpto && T.CodRetail == t.CodRetail)
        {
            TiendaWrapper tiend = new TiendaWrapper(T);
            lstTiendas.Add(tiend);
        }
    }

    return Ok(lstTiendas);
}
```

But when I call the service using Postman I get this exception. The function is supposed to receive two Id's as body and find the `Tiendas` that have those Id's

```
"$id": "1",
  "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Tienda' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
```

Any help would be great, thank you in advance.

EDIT:

This is how I call the method in Postman: http://localhost:1918/api/tiendas/GetTiendasPost
And I add the values in Body as form-data.

Comment: Can you please share how you post using postman ? What is your content-type in postman ?

Comment: How are you calling this method. Show the UI/Fiddler/Postman code

Comment: @RenatoEspinozaCarranza. you need to add a header for content type. For example if your content type is JSON then in the headers tab of postman you should add - Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Read more here http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: @Taleeb I did that, but the parameter "t" throws a null pointer exception. I don't get how to send the values to it.

Comment: See Darrel Miller's answer. Instead of application/json, set it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. See if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTTP request you need to set Content-Type to: `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the body as form data then you should use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the media type.  Unless of course you really are sending multipart data.  However, I'm not sure WebAPI is setup to process multipart forms by default.